# Problem with Vagrant : Nothing happens on vagrant up command

Tags: vagrant, powershell, virtualbox

**Versions**
Vagrant: 1.9.5
Provider: Virtualbox 5.2.30
Guest: precise32
Host: windows 7 -32bit, build:7600
Powershell: 2.0

**Vagrant destroy & up output**
nothing happens here...just an empty directory " .vagrant " is being created

**Expected behavior**
virtualbox should be picked up by vagrant

**Actual behavior**
Cursor blinks ..that's it
nothing happens on -> vagrant up and on -> vagrant global-status ->it shows "There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! "

**Possible reasons for this behavior**
I think there are some version dependecies between vagrant, virtualbox & powershell. I don't know I'm just guessing.

**NOTE**
I have read numerous official docs and similar previous issue, nothing worked. when vagrant up command is issued, it does nothing, the cursor keeps blinking forever.

**NOTE**
I know this is dumb question, I can use latest releases but is there anything I can do with this setup

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it's an Intel CPU, you may have to enable Intel VT-x in the bios. Sometimes the virtual machine will tell you this, and sometimes not. [Here's a link](https://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/) that might help (ignore the Windows 10 part since you're on Win7). Also getting everything to the newest version would be a good idea if you can.